# Issue in loading model in recommender system using streamlit

Tags: nltk, streamlit, recommendation-engine

I am building a restaurant recommender system, and I think the model is not loaded correctly. So everytime the reomm. system giving the output "Restaurant not found. Please enter a valid restaurant name." on entering the restaurant name.
Anyone can help into this.
Highly appreciated

Trying to get an output , but the system giving "Restaurant not found. Please enter a valid restaurant name."